# Custom generic list of generic class

Tags: c#-4.0, generic-list, generics

I got a class

```
public class ID_Name<T>
{
    public ID_Name(T id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public T ID { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get 
        {
            return Helper.SomeReturnValue;            
        }
    }
}
```

All I want to do is generate a custom List of ID_Name where I can pass an ID_Name.ID as parameter in Add.
I tried the following:

```
public class ID_Name_List<T> : IList<T> where T : ID_Name<T>
```

but then I get the following error:

> The type "EProtokollStatus" cannot be used as type parameter "T" in
>   the generic type or method "ID_Name_List<\T>". There is no boxing
>   conversion or type parameter conversion from "EProtokollStatus" in
>   ID_Name<\EProtokollStatus>.

I read something about this issue here: [No boxing or type parameter conversion for generic Type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823608/no-boxing-or-type-parameter-conversion-for-generic-type-parameter) but I can't see a restriction except ID_Name here. 
This may be wrong somehow, because everything I want to express is "use the same type T as in ID_Name for ID_Name_List", but how do I achieve that?

I found something here: [C#: Declaring and using a list of generic classes with different types, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590540/c-declaring-and-using-a-list-of-generic-classes-with-different-types-how) but I don't want to create many different classes for all possible types.

All I want to achieve is something like

```
ID_Name_List<EProtokollStatus> myList = new ID_Name_List<EProtokollStatus>();
myList.Add(EProtokollStatus.ValueX);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current constraint makes no sense. Did you mean:

```
public class ID_Name_List<T> : IList<ID_Name<T>>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I intended. Thanks a lot!